# How to get delve users on match skills and expertise to entered value in text box

Tags: user-information-list, delve

How can I get user information from Delve on SharePoint Online.

I have a text box on form and have to enter value (skills - SharePoint ,  .Net, Project Management  etc) and have to get all users which match Skills and expertise property of Delve to value entered in text box.

Answer (score 0):

Refer this link [Querying Office Delve Boards with JavaScript and REST](http://www.dotnetmafia.com/blogs/dotnettipoftheday/archive/2015/01/11/querying-office-delve-boards-with-javascript-and-rest.aspx) .
The link describes the way to query the information from delve using javascript and REST.